# Use URL part to create multi tenant AppEngine application

Tags: google-app-engine, multi-tenant

I'm trying different ways of implement multi tenant AppEngine web RESTful interface.
One of them is to use part of the URL as the tenant name.
The problem is that I'm using Jersey as JAX-RS implementation for RESTful interface and I would like a url such as /tenant1/res1 to first be parsed by **something** that will take the /tenant1 part, set the namespace to tenant1 and then pass the rest of the URL to Jerseys' servlet for regular handling.

The **something** maybe either ServletFilter or Servlet or something I can't think of.

How can I implement such thing?
What are the possible problems of such implementation?

Thank you,
Ido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do exactly that but using Restlet. The namespace uniquely identifies the customer that a user belongs to.

The first URL fragment contains the namespace. I verify the namespace in a RESTLET authenticator (basically a filter) and when the authenticated user does not belong to the given namespace/customer I refuse to proceed.

I use the primary key of the customer as the namespace. This has the added advantage that a valid namespace/customer can be easily (mem-)cached, and I refuse  any calls containing invalid namespaces.

Very happy with this setup and no problems encountered.